# Cascade delete in Eclipselink in a self-referencing table

Tags: sql-server, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to cascade a delete in JPA to a self-referencing table but whatever I do I get the same error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SYS_ACL", schema="dbo")
public class ACL implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected AccessControlListPK accessControlListPK;

@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Roletable roletable;

@JoinColumn(name = "VIEW_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private PageMap pagemap;

@Column(name="PARENT_ROLE")
private Long parentrole;

@Column(name="PARENT_VIEW_ID")
private Long parentview;

@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ROLE", referencedColumnName = "ROLE_ID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_VIEW_ID", referencedColumnName = "VIEW_ID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)})
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@PrivateOwned
private List<ACL> children = new LinkedList<ACL>();
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "SYSCCSSCNTRLLSTPRNTVWD". The conflict occurred in database "mydb", table "dbo.SYS_ACL" Error Code: 547
```

The database structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SYS_ACL (

VIEW_ID NUMERIC,
ROLE_ID NUMERIC,

PARENT_ROLE NUMERIC,
PARENT_VIEW_ID NUMERIC,

CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (ROLE_ID, VIEW_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK1 FORIEGN KEY (VIEW_ID) REFERENCING VIEW_TABLE(ID),
CONSTRAINT FK2 FORIEGN KEY (ROLE_ID) REFERENICNG ROLE_TABLE(ID),
CONSTRAINT FKSELF FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ROLE, PARENT_VIEW) REFERENCING SYS_ACL(ROLE_ID, VIEW_ID));
```

I can use a recursive method to delete children first but I want to know if it is possible doing that in JPA.
I'm using GF 3.1, and Eclipselink 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

What is the SQL log?

Your model seems overly complex.  You might want to remove the AccessControlListPK and just put an @Id on the @ManyToOnes.

Your issue may be cause because you are using @JoinColumn on the @OneToMany, normally you would use a mappedBy and a @ManyToOne inverse, you seem to be use @Basuc for the foreign keys instead, remove these and the join column on the OneToMany and just define a @ManyToOne to the parent.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but it is way too complicated. I need a composite key where I need to use two fields. And each is referencing to another table.

Comment: I have added my db table structure